# Syntax to append variable to {% url 'app_name:viewname' %}

Tags: django, django-templates

How do I append a variable to a url name in a template, for eg.:

```
{% for table in tables %}
      <a href="{% url 'menu:menu_view' %}">
        <button class="button table{{table.pk}}">Table {{table.pk}}</button>
      </a>
{% endfor %}
```

With `table.pk` as a counter (passed in from view function), I would like to tag it to `menu:menu_view` so that I could have `menu:menu_view1`,`menu:menu_view2`, etc.

And then I could name my `urlpatterns` as following:

```
path('<int:table.pk/', views.menu_view, name='menu_view' + str(table.pk)),
```

Comment: Why not use `<a href="{% url 'menu:menu_view' table.pk %}">`? and define the path as `path('<int:table.pk>/', views.menu_view, name='menu_view'),` then it is easy to pass any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) accepts an arbitrary number of positional and named parameters to resolve the url.

If you thus name the path:

```
path('<int:table_pk>/', views.menu_view, name='menu_view'),
```

you can use:

```
{% url 'menu_view' 2 %}                   /2/
{% url 'menu_view' table_pk=4 %}          /4/
{% url 'menu_view' table.pk %}
{% url 'menu_view' table_pk=table.pk %}
```

You thus can pass parameters to the `{% url … %}` template tag, and these are then filled in in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice solution, may I ask a doubt here sir, what is the use of `table_pk=table.pk` here since `table_pk` is already a variable thank you.

Comment: `table_pk` is the name of the variable in the `path`, `table.pk` is the value, since you pass `table` to the template, and likely not `table_pk`.